# How can I insert rows into a table for each date from periods described in another table?

Tags: mysql

Given a table `alpha`, with the following structure:

```
id INT
period_start DATE
period_end DATE
```

And a table `beta`:

```
id INT
alpha_id INT
day DATE
```

For each row in table `alpha`, I would like to insert rows into table `beta`, filling `beta.day` for each date between `alpha.period_start` and `alpha.period_end`.

For example:

```
id | period_start | period_end
1  | 2017-01-01   | 2017-01-03
```

Would be translated into:

```
id | alpha_id | day
1  | 1        | 2017-01-01
2  | 1        | 2017-01-02
3  | 1        | 2017-01-03
```

Ideas?

Comment: A search for 'MySQL Missing Dates` here on SO will give you several useful suggestions for how to proceed.  tl;dr your problem isn't trivial.

Comment: That is not my problem. I'm not trying to fill missing dates in a given period. Also, there is a lot of ways to produce the desired result with scripting - I'm looking for a pure-SQL solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but it's really inefficient. You can tweak it if you know for sure that periods are not going to be longer than a certain amount of days (the one below allows for ridiculously large periods: 99999 days, if I'm not mistaken).

```
insert into beta(alpha_id, day)
select 
    a1.id, selected_date
from 
    alpha a1 join
    (select id, selected_date from 
        (select id, adddate(@period_start, t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
            (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
            (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
            (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
            (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
            (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4,
            (select @period_start := min(period_start), @period_end := max(period_end) from alpha) init,
            (select id from alpha a3) id) v
    where selected_date <= @period_end) days on a1.id = days.id
where 
    selected_date between
        (select 
            period_start
        from 
            alpha a4
        where a1.id = a4.id) and
        (select 
            period_end
        from 
            alpha a5
        where a1.id = a5.id)
```

Personally, I'd work with procedures: more efficient, more readable... in sum, more elegant imho.

Anyway, hope it helps.

PS: I'm using an automatically incremented field for beta table's id.